How do i convert 4 digit number into decimal in c#
how to convert this value: $ 6940 usd
which is $69.40
this 6940 how do i convert that into 69.40$ USD in C#
enter image description here
I tried CEIL, FLOOR, ROUND, COMPUTE
none of them worked.
anyone pro here please help mem out
thansk you
any more quest... fee;l free to comment or aask me
sorry for the mistype baadd mechnanicla keyboard

Just divide by 100?

What program is shown in that screenshot?

Divide by 100.
Int32 number = 6940;
Decimal d = number / 100.0M;


If your value is a string (ex: "$6940") then you do:
parsedValue = Int.Parse(stringVal); parsedValue /= 100; return parsedValue; 
If your value is a number (ex 6940) then you do:
intValue /= 100; return intvalue; 
essentially, just divide by 100.
If you need your answer to have a dollar sign in front of it, do:
stringAns = "$" + intValue;
